# Find HTTP Request Initiator Line In Internet Explorer Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-11

I'm getting some odd behavior when my page is loaded in Internet Explorer 11.  When my page loads in IE 11 and I watch the Network Tab of the Developer Tools I see a HTTP Get request to the base URL of the page.  By base URL I mean the URL without any parameters.   This is causing a 500 Internal Server Error to get fired because the Action on the other side of the Request doesn't accept no Parameters.  I use Elmah to send me a mail for any unhandled exceptions so whenever a user is using IE I get a ton of Error notifications.   This is only happening in IE.  Both Firefox and Chrome work as expected.  Also, this doesn't seem to break the page in anyway.  I only know about this error because of the Emails I'm getting.  No User has reported an issue when using IE 11.

Short of searching through every line of Javascript code both 3rd party and my own is there a way in Internet Explorer Developer Tools or even another 3rd party tool that will tell me the exact line (or even js file) that initiated the Http Get Request similar to Chrome's Development Tools?

Here are some images showing the call I'm talking about.  The blacked out portion is my API Key.

The original Url being called in the below examples is `http://localhost:44301/Grower/Profile/28`

The first image is of the Internet Explorer 11 Development Tools with the offending Http Get Request highlighted.

[image: Internet Explorer 11 Development Tools]

Next is a Fiddler Screenshot of the same request highlighted.
[image: Fiddler]

And finally the Chrome Developer Tools showing no such call happening.

[image: Chrome Development Tools]

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no such a way in IE dev tools to find the initiator line of HTTP request.

But in my research, I find that we can get the file path of the HTTP request initialed using Fiddler. We can find the file path in **Inspectors -> Raw -> Referer**:

[image]

The file path in **Referer** in Fiddler is exactly the path in Initiator in Network tab in Chrome. So you could try to check the file path using Fiddler.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the research.  Unfortunately, the Referrer line isn't present for this particular call.

Comment: You can also get the Referrer from IE dev tools by selecting a request and checking the Headers tab. However, the header isn't trustworthy, might be unhelpful, or not even be set. Fiddler could help you pinpoint the actual script that caused the request, though, since it supports searching the bodies of multiple previous responses. Select all requests before the one you're interested in, open "Edit > Find Sessions…", choose to search "Responses only" and examine "Bodies only". Now try looking for parts of the URL of the relevant request, to find which script could have built it.